# docker-compose up -d <name>; No such service: <name>

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have built an image using my dockerfile with the following command:

```
docker build –t <name>:0.2.34 .
```

and then I have tried to use my docker-compose.yml:

```
strat:
  container_name: <name>
  image: <name>:0.2.34
  restart: always
  command: bash -lc 'blah'
```

to bring up my container:

```
docker-compose up -d <name>
```

Which gives me the following 'error':

```
No such service: <name>
```

Comment: docker-compose uses yml files do define your images and run them. Maybe you want to just use docker start or docker run

Comment: Can you show me an equivalent docker run command? This is something someone else wrote and I am no docker expert.

Comment: For me the issue was that I didn't have the service declared in the `docker-compose.yaml` file under the `services:` section. In case you have declared multiple services and you want to start all of them, just do `docker compose up`.

Answer (score 32):

You should run: `docker-compose up -d strat`

From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/):

> Usage: up [options] [SERVICE...]

You need to specify your **service** name, not your image name.

*Note*: You can simply run `docker-compose up -d` to start all the services that are in your docker-compose file.

Answer (score 2):

```
docker run --name <name>:0.2.34
```

This will run your built image

Comment: that will not run the container in a detached state or with the command I want to run.